# Convertir de double a BigDecimal en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una consulta ... tengo el siguiente codigo que me genera un numero Pi de 16 digitos ... pero requiero de 20 digitos, asi que crei conveniente usar el bigDecimal pero aun no se de que forma introducirlo .. me podrian ayudar (?

**Código:**

```
package io2;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MetodoBuffon {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double longitud = 4.4;
        double x1;
        double x2;
        double a;
        double b;
        double corta= 0;
        double total = 100000000;
        double n;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            a= -1 + Math.random() *2;
            b = -1 + Math.random() *2;
            x1= Math.random();
            x2 = x1 +((a* longitud)/ (Math.pow((Math.pow(a, 2)+ Math.pow(b, 2)), 0.5)));
            n= 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 1+ (1/longitud); j++) {
                if(x1 < n && n< x2){
                    corta++;
                    break;
                }
                if(x1 >n && n> x2){
                    corta++;
                    break;
                }
                n = n + longitud;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("corta: "+corta);
        double pi = (2* total)/corta;
        System.out.println("pi: "+pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente (he comentado la solución):

Código:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double longitud = 4.4;
        double x1;
        double x2;
        double a;
        double b;
        double corta = 0;
        double total = 100000000;
        double n;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            a = -1 + Math.random() * 2;
            b = -1 + Math.random() * 2;
            x1 = Math.random();
            x2 = x1 + ((a * longitud) / (Math.pow((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)), 0.5)));
            n = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 1 + (1 / longitud); j++) {
                if (x1 < n && n < x2) {
                    corta++;
                    break;
                }
                if (x1 > n && n > x2) {
                    corta++;
                    break;
                }
                n = n + longitud;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("corta: " + corta);
        double pi = (2 * total) / corta;

        // Paso 1. BigDecimal
        BigDecimal numeroLargo = new BigDecimal(pi);
        System.out.println("\nBigDecimal..........");
        System.out.println("Número largo: " + numeroLargo);

        // Paso 2. Obtener solo 20 decimales del "numeroLargo"
        DecimalFormat numero20Decimales = new DecimalFormat("#.####################");
        System.out.println("\nDecimalFormat..........");
        System.out.println("pi: " + numero20Decimales.format(numeroLargo));

    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
BigDecimal..........
Número largo: 3.34834407141696477339110060711391270160675048828125

DecimalFormat..........
pi: 3.34834407141696477339
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: ¡OYE! ¡Muchas gracias! en verdad me ha echo sufrir, pero gracias a ti ya entendi la logica :D gracias en verdad <3<3<3

Comment: @MarjorieGarcia es un placer ayudarte, para eso estamos aquí, para aprender todos juntos. Desde que te sea posible no olvides elegir mi respuesta como la Aceptada y votarla, me ayudaría mucho. Saludos!.